# Intel Graphics Control Panel alternative for Ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, hdmi, colors

Coming from a Windows 7 on a laptop with an integrated graphics card (Intel HD 3000 I think) as well as an Nvidia GT540M, I was accustomed to being able to change things like saturation and gamma of either my laptop screen or my two Dell monitors (one is on VGA, one is on HDMI) from the Intel Graphics Control Panel.

One of my two Dell S2340L monitors (the one that was on HDMI) was a lot less saturated than the one on VGA, which I solved by changing the color range of the HDMI one to full and checking the YCbCr checkbox for that one in the Intel Graphics Control Panel.

However, in Ubuntu, I cannot seem to find a program where one can adjust settings like saturation and color range for monitors.
I have tried:

- GNOME Color Manager (The one in Ubuntu settings. I do not have any calibration hardware)
- The Nvidia Settings app (This program does not have any color settings)
- DRIConf (I don't even know what this one does but I was desperate)

and I still have not found what I am looking for. 
So the big question is:

**Is there any simple screen color-management program for our beloved Ubuntu?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is built-in program called *xgamma*. You can set gamma values for red, green and blue color channels with it. Example of usage:

*$ xgamma -rgamma 2.2 -ggamma 1.8 -bgamma 2.6*

This program is installed by default. You can (and probably want to) add your *xgamma* command to Startup Applications (*Dash* -> *Startup Applications*).

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful - although xgamma only does gamma. Are there any programs that do saturation and the likes as well as gamma?