# How to disable Intel Display Power Saving Technology in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dell, display, power-management, intel-graphics

I am using Dell Inspiron 15 (3542, early 2014). There's an annoying feature which adjusts the LCD brightness according to what's displayed on the screen.

When I was using Windows 8, I disabled it from Intel HD Graphics Control Panel > Power Saving > Disable Display Power Saving Technology, and it worked fine.

Now that I'm using ubuntu (and no longer have the HD Graphics Control Panel), is there any way to disable it?

Comment: Here is the similar kind of questions you will find the solutions http://askubuntu.com/questions/483570/intel-graphics-control-panel-alternative-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the i915 driver, try the [following command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924569/linux-how-to-disable-intel-dpst-display-power-saving-technology-i915-driver):

`echo 0 > /sys/class/drm/card0/power/i915_dpst`

Comment: For me, this prints `bash: /sys/class/drm/card0/power/i915_dpst: No such file or directory`. What could be wrong?

Comment: It could be that you are not using the i915 driver

Comment: The output of `lshw -C video` under `*-display` has the line: `configuration: driver=i915 latency=0`. So I guess I am using the i915 driver.

Comment: OK, the `echo` command should create the file i915_dpst, and you are not getting a permission error, so I would examine the path in steps, from `ls /sys` to `ls /sys/class/drm/card0/power` to see where the directory tree fails

Comment: This at least doesn't work in Ubuntu 19.04. `ls /sys/class/drm/card0/power/` -> `async control rc6_residency_ms runtime_active_time  runtime_status runtime_usage autosuspend_delay_ms rc6_enable runtime_active_kids runtime_enabled runtime_suspended_time` and even with root permissions that command fails.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to: Configurations > Brightness & Lock. Set the option: "turn screen off when inactive for: Never"

I hope to help you.

Comment: At least on an external monitor it seems to ignore this setting completely :(